# Find the sum of all the natural numbers not divisible by three between one and 3¹⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰

Tags: logic, divisibility

What is the easiest way to find the sum of all the numbers

$1, 2, 3, ..., 3¹⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰$ that are not divisible by 3,

possibly by using a handheld calculator and avoiding computer processing?

Comment: Find the sum of all the numbers and then subtract the sum of the multiples of 3.

Comment: A reminder that $1+2+3+\dots+n = n(n+1)/2$

Comment: Do you have a handheld calculate with roughly 66,000 digits?  What would it even mean to calculate this without an electronic computer?

Comment: Hmm, closer to 95,000 digits.

Comment: I think it is very difficult to prove which is the easiest way. First one must find some measure of "ease".

Answer (score 3):

Hints: 
 1) How many numbers in that range are multiples of 3? 
 2) If you divide each of those numbers by 3, you get 1, 2, ..., k. What is the sum of those numbers?
 3) Now add the numbers from 1 to $3^{100000}$ and subtract the sum above.

Comment: This is how I started. I found the sum of all the numbers between one and 3¹⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰ and then tried to find the sum of all the numbers divisible by three. Now, how do can I determine the last number in this sequence that is divisible by three so that I could build the sum of those numbers? Also, this is an old Finnish high school maths finals question (one from the beginning of the exam) that has no answers on the web.

Comment: The last number in the sequence that is divisible by 3 is clearly $3^{100000}$!

Comment: @rogerl +1 for figuring out my mistake. since you did it in a comment I'm upvoting you here :)

Comment: @rogerl by your logic, $1<3^{100000}<3^{100000}$ in this comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175128/find-the-sum-of-all-the-natural-numbers-not-divisible-by-three-between-one-and-3#comment4477798_2175133